# Spring Boot 2.2.4 in test bootstrap.properties not loading included application.properties profiles

Tags: spring-boot

While upgrading to spring boot version 2.2.4 from 2.1.6 I am getting the issue.

*Issue Scenario:*

I have a spring boot test that uses the `bootstrap-test.proeprties` and test as an active profile. The `bootstrap-test.properties` also include some other profiles which are defined by `application.properties` config files.

Below is the sample code :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SampleTest {

   @Test
    public void sampleTest() {

    }
}


//bootstrap-test.properties

spring.profiles.include=db
```

Here properties present in `application-db.properties` the file is not loaded and the test fails. This was working fine with spring-boot version 2.1.x. Is something changed in the new boot

version?

It is working fine if I change the `bootstrap-test.properties` to `application-test.properties`. But still 
I will need the bootstrap file as I have  Spring Cloud Config Server properties which needs to be loaded in the start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What spring cloud version you are using? We also had the same issue while upgrading to boot 2.2.4. You should upgrade the spring cloud version to `Hoxton.SR1` with boot 2.2.4 .